Issue in Monaco editor while shrinking its size in react/next.js project
I am trying to integrate monaco editor in my next.js 14 project using tailwindcss. I have wrapped Editor inside a container div. I have created a child component to show monaco editor on the web page and loading it from a parent component. Here is the code:
Parent component (TSX):
    <CodeEditor
      ref={editorRef}
      language={useProgrammingLang.value}
      theme={theme?.toString().toLowerCase()}
      fontSize={editorSettings?.fontSize}
      fontFamily={editorSettings?.fontFamily}
      defaultValue={codeSnippet}
      loading={<TbLoader3 />}
    />

Main editor child component TSX (CodeEditor):
 <div className="size-full">
    <Editor
      height="100%"
      width="100%"
      defaultLanguage={language}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      theme={`vs-${theme}`}
      onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
      onChange={handleEditorChange}
      loading={loading}
      options={{
        readOnly: false,
        lineNumbers: 'on',
        fontSize:
          typeof fontSize === 'string' ? parseInt(fontSize, 10) : fontSize,
        fontFamily,
        automaticLayout: true,
        glyphMargin: false,
        minimap: { enabled: true },
        scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
        wordWrap: 'off',
        tabSize: 4,
        cursorStyle: 'line',
        formatOnPaste: true,
        dragAndDrop: false,
        showFoldingControls: 'mouseover',
      }}
    />
  </div>

Now, I have a expandable sidebar on the left side of page. On right side, I am loading this monaco editor on web page. I can close/open sidebar with an icon. Editor expands its width well when I close the sidebar, but when I open sidebar again, editor size should decrease its width according to parent container, but it is creating scroll on the page and not shrinking its size properly according to container.
It is not an issue with sidebar. It happens even when I zoom out page and zoom in again, it created scrolls on the page.
Reference links:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor

I believe the issue lies with the class name size-full of the editor container <div className="size-full">.
Try setting the height to a fixed value such as 800px or 80vh by adding a class such as h-[80vh] so that Monaco Editor does not assume there is unlimited space to fill.
If that doesn't work, try limiting the height of the editor component by passing a value less than 100% via the height prop like so height="90%".
Hope that helps!
